# need to stop initv service before rpm removal/upgrade?

Tags: rpm, services, rpmbuild

Is there a need to stop a service *before* performing the removal or upgrade of the service's RPM package?

Normally, what the RPM package manager does when performing an upgrade is to install the new package first, then remove the old one. Excerpt:

```
Run %pre from "software-2".
Place files from "software-2".
Run %post from "software-2".
Run %preun from "software-1".
Delete files unique to "software-1".
Run %postun from "software-1".
```

In this case, shouldn't the service be stopped in %pre before installing the new package?

Here is a portion of my specfile for reference:

```
%preun
# do not run if this is an upgrade
if [ $1 -eq 0 ]; then
  /sbin/service myservice stop > /dev/null 2>&1
  /sbin/chkconfig --del /etc/init.d/myservice
fi
exit 0

%post
/sbin/chkconfig --add /etc/init.d/myservice
exit 0
```

What I have is what everyone seems to be doing and I do not understand why this would work in the case of an upgrade, without stopping the service first in %pre.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've forgotten how UNIX filesystems work. As long as the link-loader leaves the object files open then the process will see the object files it was started with, as it holds a handle to the now-removed file. Once that handle is close()ed then the file is actually removed.  So it is safe to leave the daemon running whilst deleting and installing new object files.

Of course it's the old version of the daemon which is running, so 'safe' isn't so safe if the upgrade is to address a security issue. Which is why Debian's APT has a different policy and stop/starts daemons upon an upgrade.

You might find this [specification](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Packaging:Scriptlets?rd=Packaging:ScriptletSnippets#Syntax) on RPM scriptlets to be useful if you want to alter your package's policy.

Comment: Thank you! I've noticed you employed the term _object_ files. I'd venture to guess that for "data" files, this could be a problem? For example, if the service still residing in memory is attempting to access a file that used to belong to the package, but is no longer present. Wouldn't it just be safer to shutdown services beforehand in order to avoid edge cases like these?

Comment: In some rare cases yes. But usually the few seconds or even minutes between upgrade of the files and restart of the service is not a problem. If you think this can be a problem then I recommend a project Atomic for you. It upgrade system packages in different path and then require reboot and during reboot it will swap symlinks and the upgrade is atomic. https://www.projectatomic.io/

Comment: Yep. If you read between the lines of my answer you'll see I don't think much of this choice in the design of RPM. But exploring that more explicitly in the answer is to dilute information with editorial. Note that the current Fedora recommendation is to use PackageKit to do a update between two reboots (see "pkcon"). That reboot  necessarily restarts all daemons. So this Q is increasingly moot.